# hamburger menu won't close after clicking on the menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am having an issue with my bootstrap hamburger menu. When I click on the menu, it opens to display the links within, but when I click on it again or click anyway on the screen, it doesn't close the menu and I can't see what's causing this to break.

Is there a way to fix it? Even including some javascript or jquery as a workaround to toggle close or opening will help.

Below is the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/../style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

```
<section id="nav-bar">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/../#"><img src="../img/logo.png"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#top">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#about">ABOUT US</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#courses">OUR COURSES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#services">OUR SERVICES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/../#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a>
              </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#contact">CONTACT US</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

style.css

```
/*----------Navigation-------*/
#nav-bar
{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
.navbar-brand img
{
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.navbar-nav li
{
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.navbar-nav li a
{
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav-bar ul li a:hover
{
    color: #747c85!important;
}
.navbar
{
    background: #fff;
}
.navbar-toggler
{
    border: none!important;
}
.nav-link
{
    color: #555!important;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: i am seeing it working fine , when you click on hamburger icon it opens the menu and when you click on it again then it will close the menu ... thats how bootstrap menu works ...

Comment: @samairali It's strange, it doesn't work for me. I can prove it. If you go to our website https://www.metis-online.com and click the hamburger menu in there to open and then try to close it, it doesn't do it. And I copied the same code from there that deals with the navigation onto my question. You'll have to make screen smaller so header links become hamburger menu

Comment: I checked the site. It doesn't seem to work on me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your html structure, there are many html tags, body tags and head sections misplaced. I removed some to test and at some point the menu worked, but of course the correct solution is to clean and order the entire structure.

Comment: I'm going to have to see what you did to clean it up. Put it through validator and yeah some little issues but didn't mention issue with html structure.

Comment: [Here is a HTML validation report](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.metis-online.com%2F), what I mean by 'cleaning' it is removing all the stray tags and keep the [html basic structure and order](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template)

Comment: Hmmm.... I wonder if the structure is slightly whack because I am using a php <?php include where I am including a php file that contains html so that file contains head ansd body and so does the current page as well. Basically I created a header.php page and that gets included on all pages

Comment: See comment I am posting to other answer as I think what may be problem. May still need some guidence to get through this little tricky issue if issue is cleaning uo

Comment: This was actually the correct answer, HTML structure messed it up

Answer (score 1):

When I took your code into my own computer and examined it, I saw it was working. But the problem is that I prefer to keep bootstrap codes between body tags. Your problem may be caused by this. Choose body labels instead of Head labels. Also check your bootstrap links. May be incorrect.

!! İmportant:

There may be another problem. If you are using media query on your site, please check media query in the section where the navbar is responsive. A styling in that section may have produced incorrect results!!

```css
/*----------Navigation-------*/
#nav-bar
{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
.navbar-brand img
{
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.navbar-nav li
{
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.navbar-nav li a
{
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav-bar ul li a:hover
{
    color: #747c85!important;
}
.navbar
{
    background: #fff;
}
.navbar-toggler
{
    border: none!important;
}
.nav-link
{
    color: #555!important;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Website Design</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
>


</head>

<body>

<section id="nav-bar">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/../#"><img src="../img/logo.png"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#top">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#about">ABOUT US</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#courses">OUR COURSES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#services">OUR SERVICES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/../#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a>
              </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#contact">CONTACT US</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's crazy. Tried even adding your code, comment out css to take out the affect of `@media`, even put back in the css and removed all instances of `@media` (none relating to nav bar), still not working.

Comment: this is really weird. if you upload all of your code that concerns the homepage as snippets, we can review it in more detail.

Comment: Yeah what I'll do is a complete strip version of just the relevant html and css and update it in the question, give me 15 mins

Comment: I think I know what might be causing it. May still need your advice along with serge on this.

Comment: Ok so I have figured out what is causing it and I think it's related to the HTML structure. My problem is how to fix it and I will explain why I think it's difficult and may need guidance...

Comment: So.I placed your html and CSS in separate files and it worked perfectly. So then I thought ok why did it not work on mine when I copied and pasted and here is the issue. So imagine your html code you have place in your answer is a header. To me, I want a head on every page but lets say if a header changes, I don't want to go into every page and change the header, so I use what's called <?php include header.php> in all pages...

Comment: Now header.php has its own head, body and html tags and so does every other page, so when I place <?php include header.php> in each html page, we are going to have this issue where the structure may look wrong because we will have multiple head tags, body tags, html tags etc and I am sure that is the issue

Comment: More info on using php includes is here: https://css-tricks.com/the-simplest-ways-to-handle-html-includes/

Comment: Oh no, I figured it, remove head, body tags, html tags etc from files which I will use php include to keep the structure. Now if you try the webiste it works

Comment: Actually ı was sleep sorry. Good morning by the way  :) glad you succeed